# Flutter dispose provider notifyListners()

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple controller like this

```
class MatchListController with ChangeNotifier {
  List<MatchData> liveMatches = [];

  MatchListController() {
    getMatchList();
  }

  getMatchList() async {
    debugPrint('match list api called');
    var response = await ApiService().matchList();
    if (response != null) {
      final databody = json.decode(response);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

When my page loads it runs the function `getMatchList()` which is fine but If I change the page between function and when it return data `notifyListeners` hit and app crash. I am using loading but I have tab menu so I can change the page from there What I want is if page is close then notifyListeners dispose.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that khalil mentioned is correct, there is also another solution:

Since you are using loading, I assume you want to prevent the page from changing, so you can wrap the tab menu buttons with an `AbsorbPointer` widget, and use `setState` to change its absorbing state according to your loading state. Your loading state can simply be a boolean inside your stateful widget.

Comment: That's a good solution as well!